# XSL Grouping by nested parameter

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file like this

```
<fruits>
  <fruit>
    <name>banana</name>
    <country>Morocco</country>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>orange</name>
    <country>Morocco</country>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>grape</name>
    <country>Egypt</country>
  </fruit>
 </fruits>
```

And I need to group it in another way:

```
<fruits>
  <country name="Morocco">
    <fruit>
      <name>banana</name>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
      <name>orange</name>
    </fruit>
  </country>
  <country name="Egypt">
    <fruit>
      <name>grape</name>
    </fruit>
  </country>
</fruits>
```

I tried to make it with `for-each-group` from XSLT 2.0, but it wasn't good at all: I don't know how to handle grouping by nested parameters, so my .xsl file doesn't do anything good.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:for-each-group select="fruits/fruit" group-by="fruits/fruit/country">
    <country name="{country}">
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <fruit>
          <name> '{name}'/</name>
        </fruit>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </country>
  </xsl:for-each-group>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're close - the `group-by` expression is an XPath relative to the `select`ed nodes, so you only need to `group-by="country"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="fruit" group-by="country">
        <country name="{country}">
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <fruit>
              <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
              </name>
            </fruit>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </country>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or a somewhat cleaner approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="fruit" group-by="country">
        <country name="{country}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
        </country>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="fruit/country" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Either one, when run on your sample input, produces:

```
<fruits>
   <country name="Morocco">
      <fruit>
         <name>banana</name>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
         <name>orange</name>
      </fruit>
   </country>
   <country name="Egypt">
      <fruit>
         <name>grape</name>
      </fruit>
   </country>
</fruits>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are limited to XSLT 1.0 then there are a few ways to do it: none of them neat. This one looks for all `<fruit>` elements that have no preceding siblings with the same country. It then copies the `<country>` element, followed by a new `<fruit>` node for itself and each following sibling with the same country.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/fruits">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fruit">
    <xsl:if test="not(country = preceding-sibling::fruit/country)">
      <country>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="../fruit[country=current()/country]">
          <fruit>
            <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
          </fruit>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </country>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fruits>
   <country name="Morocco">
      <fruit>
         <name>banana</name>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
         <name>orange</name>
      </fruit>
   </country>
   <country name="Egypt">
      <fruit>
         <name>grape</name>
      </fruit>
   </country>
</fruits>
```

---

The *Muenchian Method* speeds up this query by using the `key` facility of XSLT, and can be useful with sizeable data sets. This alternative solution declares the key `fruit-by-country` so that all `<fruit>` elements with the same value for the `<country>` element can be selected using, say, `key('fruit-by-country', 'Morocco')`. The template uses the key to check whether the current `<fruit>` is the first one with this value for `<country>`, and also to select all fruits in the same group so that they can be displayed together. The output is identical to that of the previous transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="fruit-by-country" match="fruit" use="country" />

  <xsl:template match="/fruits">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fruit">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('fruit-by-country', country)[1])">
      <country>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('fruit-by-country', country)">
          <fruit>
            <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
          </fruit>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </country>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Even in XSLT 1.0, Muenchian grouping is far preferable to grouping with `preceding-sibling`.

Comment: @JLRishe: I agree that it is more efficient, but it is also (even more) opaque and incomprehensible. So it depends what you mean by *preferable*. You have made your point, but a downvote says that my answer is *not useful*. Are you really prepared to say that about it?

Comment: This is simply my opinion, but I view grouping with `preceding-sibling` as a bad practice, even if it is a little easier to understand. Your answer is also incorrect. Please carefully compare your output to OP's desired output.

Comment: Moreover, the OP made it quite clear that a 2.0 solution was desired.

Comment: That's closer, but still incorrect. :) Closely observe where the `country` elements are in relation to the `fruit` elements.

Comment: @JLRishe: Sheesh. Thanks. The odd indentation of the XML in the question fooled me. I've corrected my code.